# Load ASP.NET MVC strongly typed partial view on radiobutton click

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two strongly Typed partial views (Developers list and Testers list) and the respective views are Developers.ascx and Testers.ascx

Now I want to load one partial view based on the radiobutton selected.
How to read the value of the radiobutton option?
I would appreciate if anyone can provide Code snippet or some guidelines.

Appreciate your time!

Here is my parent  Controller Code & View:

Parent Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult View IT People List(string type)
{
    var developers = from d in itEntity.Developers select s; 
    return View(developers); 
}
```

Parent View:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Mvc.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<DataModel.Developers>>" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphHead" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphContent" runat="server">
    <h2>View All IT Dept List</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td class="Form_Label"><label for="txType">Select List:</label>  </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.RadioButton("Type", 1, true)%> Developers&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= Html.RadioButton("Type", 2, false)%> Testers
            </td>        
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan = 2>
            <%Html.RenderPartial("Developers", Model);%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Two strongly Typed Controllers are:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Developers()
{ 
var developers = from d in itEntity.Developers select d; return View(developers);
}


[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Testers()
{ 
var testers = from t in itEntity.Testers select t; return View(testers);
}
```

Thanks
Rita

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input:radio[name=Type]').change(function() {
    var url = '/Home/Developers';
    if ($(this).val() === '2') {
        url = '/Home/Testers';
    }
    $("#result").load(url);
});
```

Comment: radio button change event is not firing? Any clue?

Comment: Thankyou!! Was stuck trying to figure out why my radiobuttonlist wasn't firing on change or click - this syntax works yay :)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to do an ajax call that returns the html from the partial views (on the radio button click). Then use jQuery again to modify the html of your page.

Look at the [$.ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) and [$.html](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html) documentation for details.